# ESTA Address Help

Tags: usa, esta

I usually go to USA to visit my fiancee so her home address is the one on my ESTA. My next trip to the USA I will be going to Las Vegas together with her (she'll meet me there). Do I need to update my ESTA address to the hotel we're staying at in Vegas? I don't want to be refused entry or face issues because of this.

I heard it was not a requirement but I cannot determine if this is true or not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[This CBP ESTA Page](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/frequently-asked-questions-about-visa-waiver-program-vwp-and-electronic-system-travel) says:

> Does a traveler ever need to reapply for travel authorization through ESTA?
>
> Yes, a new travel authorization via ESTA is required when: (1) the traveler is issued a new passport; (2) the traveler changes his or her name; (3) the traveler changes his or her gender; (4) the traveler’s country of citizenship changes; or (5) the circumstances underlying the traveler’s previous responses to any of the ESTA application questions requiring a “yes” or “no” response have changed.

Unless one of the five triggers has occurred, you do not need to update or amend your ESTA information.